# UI control not display content in custom tableviewcell with storyboard

Tags: uitableview, storyboard, custom-controls, reuseidentifier, registerclass

I don't understand why the label i had in my storyboard don't show up when a run the app with IOS8 and XCODE 6.1.1
[image]
I have bound my label to a custom UiTableviewCell and i can set the text but my label don't appear in the subview of the content view of the cell return by `tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

If a using `[self.tableView registerClass:[NewGameCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ListNewGameCell"];`
I can't use the storyboard.

I read all the others question and i can't find the answer.
Thanks

Comment: Do you know why my UiLabel is not initialise in the controller of the custom cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'm so stupid !

The UILabel doesn't show up because i add it only for iPad and i my simulator was on iPhone.
Thank for your help